# 301 redirect www and non www to a new domain but same file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have found many topics here but i can't find how to make permanent redirect for both non www and www domain to new non www domain?

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress# 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.eu%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This seams to be working i would just like to know is there too much of a code here or is it ok like this ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d probably turn this around, and put your new rules above `# BEGIN WordPress` – otherwise WP routing will start to do its work before your redirect to the new domain; and that would mean a file system lookup of whether a folder or file matching the request exists.

Your rewrite to the new domain still works, because you used `REQUEST_URI` in there; that value stays the same during the rewriting, other than the internal current URI the system is working with – had you used `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.eu/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]` instead, because of WP routing above what you capture with `(.*)` might just be `index.php` right now.
But once the user arrives on the new domain, WP routing will kick in again, and go check the file system *again*.

If however you rewrite to the new domain first, it will not get to the point of the WP routing rules, so they don’t need to be tested for “under” the old domain.

---

Apart from that, your rules seem fine; and this is about as little code as you can get to achieve this thing. Performance should be no issue, too (once you fix the order thing, as I explained.)

Comment: I forgot to ask , is it seo friendly, will google and others crawl it the right way ?

Comment: If a URL changes permanently, then a 301 status code is the right way to go. (If not all “old” URLs exist under your new domain any more, you should also see to it that those requests are either redirected to the new address, if applicable, or answered with a 404 or 410 status code.)